# Correct interaction with GridView

Tags: c#, windows-8

In Windows 8 App (Pc + Tablet) (C#) I have GridView.
Which event I need to use, to correct realize that:

On PC

1. Left Key Mouse Click = do something (like open new page or another)
2. Right Key Mouse Click = make this item "is selected".

On Tablet

1. Tap = do something (like open new page or another)
2. Little drag to bottom (standard selection) = make this item "is selected".

I'm looking for elegant solution, where I need to use minimum numbers of events

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 handles most of this events for you. In the most situations you don't have to use explicit events to achieve what you want.

Rather than using the `LeftMouseClick` or `OnTap` you should use native Control Events like `ItemSelected` etc.

If your goals are not covered by those events I would recommend using a Behavior where you subscribe to your Events and publish the same logic to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ItemClick event. You will just need to set the IsItemClickEnabled to True. The item you clicked is sent as an argument of the event.
You just have to set a selection mode to enable the selection.